# Server startup in 1680 ms:why I am getting this error

Tags: servlets

Whenever I am going to run my project I am getting this error frequently.please let me know what is the reason behind it.serverstartup in 1680.I googled a lot but not getting any solution of it.I created a new workspace also but getting this same problem.

```
Dec 22, 2012 11:35:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in      
production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java
\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java
 /jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib

 /i386;c:\program files\dell\dw wlan card;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows   
 \system32\wbem;C:\Windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;c:\program files\java
 \jdk1.6.0_25\bin;c:\program files\ibm\gsk8\lib;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
  Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:     \Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn
   \;B:\eclipse;;.

      Dec 22, 2012 11:35:31 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
   WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property   

   'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:RESTfulProject' did not find a matching property.

Dec 22, 2012 11:35:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init

  INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]

     Dec 22, 2012 11:35:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init

    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]

   Dec 22, 2012 11:35:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load

   INFO: Initialization processed in 742 ms

  Dec 22, 2012 11:35:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal

   INFO: Starting service Catalina

  Dec 22, 2012 11:35:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal

  INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.8
    Dec 22, 2012 11:35:31 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClasspathResourceConfig init
   INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the paths:
     B:\XYRAD\XyRadwebservicesMoon\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core   
      \tmp6\wtpwebapps\RESTfulProject\WEB-INF\lib

   B:\XYRAD\XyRadwebservicesMoon\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core
   \tmp6\wtpwebapps\RESTfulProject\WEB-INF\classes

   Dec 22, 2012 11:35:32 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClasspathResourceConfig init
   INFO: Root resource classes found:

   class webService.FeedService

  Dec 22, 2012 11:35:32 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClasspathResourceConfig init

   INFO: Provider classes found:
   Dec 22, 2012 11:35:33 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
   INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
  Dec 22, 2012 11:35:33 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
       INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
   Dec 22, 2012 11:35:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
     INFO: Server startup in 1680 ms
```

Comment: INFO: Server startup in 1680 ms is telling that your server has started successfully, there is no error.

Comment: no output is showing . Giving error : Http status 404

Comment: HTTP Status 404 means The Requested resource is not found. which URL you are requesting. can you paste the code here.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/RESTfulProject/REST/webservices/GetFeeds

Comment: Even I created a new work space then also I  got this problem